# How to change atom map in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure, and i need to update two values inside this atom:

```
(def app-state (atom {:id "1":status 0 :st 0}))
```

Im using the following:

```
(let [value (mod (+ (:st @app-state) 1) 4)]
    (swap! app-state update-in [:status] value)
    (swap! app-state update-in [:st] inc))
```

Im getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Comment: What is your intent with `update-in [:status] value`? Like the error says, `value` is a `long`, not a function. Did you mean `assoc :status value` instead?

Comment: Note that if that is your intent, it would be better written like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/ac29fb11efec4468a127c182df5847e2). You don't need the `-in` versions of the function since you aren't changing nested parts. I also wouldn't use two sepeate `swap!`s. In theory, another operation could happen between the two calls to `swap!`, and that may mess with things depending on how you have things set up. If you want the whole thing to be one atomic action, it should be one call.

Comment: It also probably isn't a good idea that `value` definition is dereferencing the atom. That should be tucked inside of the `swap!` call as well. The data could have changed between the definition of `value` and the time `swap!` is called.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that is exactly what im trying to do, i tried like this: https://pastebin.com/QB6yJZjM . Is this the right way? Thanks

Comment: Don't deref the app-state inside of `swap`. Just use `%`. That is the atoms value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third argument to `update-in` takes a function but you are supplying a long (`value`) which is why you get an exception. You could use `assoc-in` instead which takes the value to associate in the map directly:

```
(swap! app-state assoc-in [:status] value)
```

However you should do the entire update to the state atomically within the function passed to `swap!` e.g.

```
(swap! app-state (fn [{:keys [st] :as state}]
                    (let [st-next (inc st)
                          value (mod st-next 4)]
                       (merge state {:st st-next
                                     :status value}))))
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why to not use a simple helper function like this (or why it doesn't exist in the first place?). (defn atom-set [atom key val] (swap! atom (fn [state] (assoc state key val))))

Comment: @JoelM - You can just use `(swap! atom assoc key val)` for that. `swap!` passes the existing state as the first argument to the update function (`assoc` in this case) followed by any other arguments you provide (`key` and `val` here).

Answer (score 3):

Below is a repl session based on your problem. First I define `app-state` exactly as you posted. Next, I define `bump-state` as an anonymous function `#(…)` that takes one argument, the current value of `app-state`, denoted by the `%` placeholder. The `let` form binds the incremented value of the `:st` key to `st`. Finally, `assoc` returns a new immutable map by associating new values with `:st` and `:status` of the previous map.

The next several lines just call `swap!` to confirm that `bump-state` works. The last line just defines the anonymous function directly in the call to `swap!`. While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58099897/12135561) works fine, I think this is a little more succinct.

```
user=> (def app-state (atom {:id "1":status 0 :st 0}))
#'user/app-state
user=> (def bump-state #(let [st (inc (:st %))] (assoc % :st st :status (mod st 4))))
#'user/bump-state
user=> (swap! app-state bump-state)
{:id "1", :status 1, :st 1}
user=> (swap! app-state bump-state)
{:id "1", :status 2, :st 2}
user=> (swap! app-state bump-state)
{:id "1", :status 3, :st 3}
user=> (swap! app-state bump-state)
{:id "1", :status 0, :st 4}
user=> (swap! app-state #(let [st (inc (:st %))] (assoc % :st st :status (mod st 4))))
{:id "1", :status 1, :st 5}
```

The whole idea of `swap!` is that your update function operates on the current immutable value held by the atom and returns a new immutable value to replace it with. Your update function is simply a pure function, which lets you reason about it more easily and also play with it at the repl, just like other functions.